# Cant Schedule Job ErpConfigContext

Tags: java, hana, sap-cloud-sdk

i'm trying Schedule a job with Quartz and Cant Schedule ErpConfigContext , when i do a request, works fine.

But in scheduled job, this return a error.

//Request working

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    new ODataScheduledFetch().execute();
}
```

//Job class not working
public class JobProductPricing  implements Job {

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new ODataScheduledFetch().execute();

}
```

}

ODataScheduledFetch().execute(), do some thinks and call this method, 
and when execute query.execute(new ErpConfigContext()); return a error only on Schedule Job

```
private boolean tryRequestERP(ODataQuery query,ODataQueryResult[] queryResult) {
    boolean boReturn=false;
    try {
        //queryResult 
        queryResult[0]  = query.execute(new ErpConfigContext());
        boReturn = true;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        String error = e.toString();
        System.out.println(error);
        boReturn = false;

    }

    return boReturn;
}
```

And received this error:

[
com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get ConnectivityConfiguration: 
no RequestContext available. Have you correctly configured a RequestContextServletFilter or have you wrapped your logic in a 
RequestContextExecutor when executing background tasks that are not triggered by a request?
]

on this [Creating ErpConfigContext threw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004203/creating-erpconfigcontext-threw-exception)

has a answer that i dont get...

"
EDIT: Note that when running your code in a background job (not triggered by a request), you have to wrap your code with RequestContextExecutor::execute.

"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code sample I assume you are not using Spring Boot, which is the focus of the linked question.

What you need to do is wrapping your scheduled call into a [`RequestContextExecutor::execute`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContextExecutor.html) call. For your example it would look like this:

```java
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    new RequestContextExecutor().execute(() -> {
        new ODataScheduledFetch().execute();
    });
}
```

Depending on what you do inside your `ODataScheduledFetch::execute` call you might need to use the [`JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/security/JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor.html) (on CloudFoundry only).

---

For a bit mor background:

All `*Accessor` classes (e.g. [`TenantAccessor`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/tenant/TenantAccessor.html), [`DestinationAccessor`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/connectivity/DestinationAccessor.html)) rely on a so called [`RequestContext`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContext.html) to be available in the current Thread/Request. Such a `RequestContext` is created by the `RequestContextExecutor` as described above.

To make your life easier in the usual use-case (which is on receiving Requests) we automatically load the [`RequestContextServletFilter`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContextServletFilter.html) which wraps all incoming Requests for you.

That is the reason why your code works in a Request but not scheduled.